# Face mesh not attached to rig!

Tags: mesh, rigging

I followed this tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SBYb1YmaOMY

To rig my character. No problems until I move the rig at the end, the eyes,nose and mouth mesh on my character (a joined part to the main body) does not move!

[image]

Please help! Thanks!

Comment: Your character lookin’ kinda sus without the face, lol. I’m guessing the YouTube tutorial involved automatic weights. If I remember right, these do not work well on disconnected pieces. I recommend in this case that you manually assign the vertices of the unmoving part to the vertex group with the same name as the bone it’s supposed to move with (since it seems the face isn’t supposed to bend, this should be easy).

Answer (score 0):

Go to edit mode, select all not moving vertices, go to mesh properties (green triangle with 3 dots icon), vertex group tab, select the vertex group which has the same name of your head bone, click the "Assign" button.